# Jquery + html img tag

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i have a list of images

```
images =    '<img id="new" src="../../public/images/badges/newbw.png" alt="" width="60" title="Newbie: Shared first featured campaign" height="60">' +
                '<img id="new1" src="../../public/images/badges/swbw.png" alt="" width="60" title="Newbie: Shared first featured campaign" height="60">'+
                '<img id="new2" src="../../public/images/badges/sswbw.png" alt="" width="60" title="Newbie: Shared first featured campaign" height="60">'+
                '<img id="new3" src="../../public/images/badges/adbw.png" alt="" width="60" title="Newbie: Shared first featured campaign" height="60">' +
                '<img id="new4" src="../../public/images/badges/expbw.png" alt="" width="60" title="Newbie: Shared first featured campaign" height="60">'+
                '<img id="new5" src="../../public/images/badges/supbw.png" alt="" width="60" title="Newbie: Shared first featured campaign" height="60">';
```

now i would like to replace only 
`img id="new"`
 to new image `<img id="new" src="../../public/images/badges/new.png" alt="" width="60" title="Newbie: Shared first featured campaign" height="60">`

maintaining others as it was. I find very hard as my jquery knowledge is limited.How i can do it in jquery.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at what you want to replace it with, it seems you only wish to change the `src` property.

As no other elements in the string contain the same `src`, you could do a javascript replace:

```
images = images.replace("../../public/images/badges/newbw.png", "../../public/images/badges/new.png");
```

Alternatively, once this string has been **added to the DOM***, you could use jQuery to change the value:

```
$("#new").attr("src", "../../public/images/badges/new.png");
```

---

***Note**: You cannot use `$("#new")` until the string `images` has been added to the DOM, because jQuery selectors only work by finding matching elements in your HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

So you need to change only the "src" property of the image with id="new".
Using jQuery, you need this:

```
$("#new").attr("src","../../public/images/badges/new.png");
```

Here you select the exact image with `$("#new")` and change its "src" attribute by calling the `attr()` function on it.

Answer (score 0):

At first. IDs are unique. You can't have two elements with same ID. id="new" is attach to two elements.

Now to change the src of img that has id equals to new.

```
$("#new").attr("src", "WRITE HERE THE NEW IMAGE PATH")
```